# Updating hours with text and dashes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out how to add +8hours to a schedule formatted with a text in front and a dash in between the hours. Please see example below:

Training 01:45AM - 02:45AM

Convert that time to +8 hours.

Training 09:45AM - 10:45AM.

I just cant seem to figure out the best formula to use in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the raw data string from your post were in A2, this should work:

`=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\d.+M) -"),TEXT(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\d.+M) -"))+TIME(8,0,0),"hh:mmAM/PM")),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"- (\d.+M)"),TEXT(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"- (\d.+M)"))+TIME(8,0,0),"hh:mmAM/PM"))`

In short, this formula uses `REGEXEXTRACT` to pull each time from the string, convert it to a value, add eight hours, convert it back to `TEXT` and finally reinsert that transformed substring back into the original string with `REGEXREPLACE`. Because this happens twice, you'll see two such setups, one wrapped within the other.

Comment: Hi, 

Not sure what this means. But, im getting this error.

Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "(\d.+M) -" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "Training 22:30 - 22:45".

Comment: In your original post, you showed the string format this way: "Training 01:45AM - 02:45AM." The formula is based on that exact format, so it is looking for twelve-hour time iwith "AM/PM" But in your comment, the error message shows that it's looking at "Training 22:30 - 22:45," which is 24-hour time and does not have the "AM/PM" as shown in your original post. We can only write formulas based on what you show us.

Comment: Ralph, do you still need help with this? Please do try to keep up with your post while it is active, to help avoid confusion and inefficient use of time for those here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Yes, 

I still need help. The correct string format should be Training 01:45AM - 02:45AM. 

Thank you!

Comment: If your format is "Training 01:45AM - 02:45AM" then the formula I already supplied should work. It wasn't working on the format from your first comment, which was not the same (i.e., "Training 22:30 - 22:45").